# Understanding Conda installation error messages: 'Failed to solve environment' and 'Retrying with flexible solve'

Tags: python, conda

I tried to download a Python package `pysam` using `conda`

```
conda install -c bioconda pysam
```

Then I got:

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done
```

Finnaly, I succeed in downloading `pysam`

But I'm confused and curious about the shell output:

1. What's the meaning of `Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.` and `Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.`?
2. What's the difference between `current_repodata.json` and `repodata.json`?

Answer (score 1):

1. When you try to install a new package, conda will look all versions of that new package (from `repodata.json`) and check for any dependency conflicts with your existing environment. This is the **frozen solve**. However, if there are no compatible versions that won't conflict with your existing environment, conda will then try to modify your existing package version to search for a potentially compatible combination. This is the **flexible solve**.
2. `repodata.json` holds all packages' metadata across all versions, and is used to solve dependency conflicts when installing packages. `current_repodata.json` is a subset of `repodata.json` that only holds the metadata of the newest version of the packages.